# how to set Section with String @"XYZ" as first section in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, core-data

I am populating my TableView with data from coreData.
I want to set an Section with a special String as always the first Section in the TableView.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method when using with coreData:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)] autorelease];
    if(section == 0) {

        UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 40);
        label.text = @"XYZ";

        [headerView addSubview:label];
        [label release];

    }
    return headerView;
}
```

Implement this method if you are using the built-in view from UITableView:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0) {
        return @"XYZ";
    }
    return @"";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. i am populating the tableview with data from coreData. And i am using the method **-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section**. I want to move the whole SET with the ROWS.